# What is the most efficient way to effect a voltage drop in a dc cct?

Tags: voltage-divider

I have a 24V supply and need to drop the supply voltage to 19V to power a TV set.

The plug pack that powers the TV states the output as 19V and the current at 2.1A

I could use a resistor to drop the voltage but it would need to have a high power rating. Can anyone suggest a cct using easily obtained components to solve this problem?

Comment: You _cannot_ use a resistor because the load is variable. The easiest solution is buy a cheap buck converter board from your online retailer of choice. If you want to make your own from scratch, start researching buck converter designs.

Comment: 19v is the *de facto* standard output for laptop power supplies. Buy a generic one of those, or ask around family and friends for somebody who's junked their old laptop and still has the supply.

Comment: "easily obtained components" - what components are available to you? You give no address in your profile nor a hint of why what I consider to be easy-to-get might be problematic to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use a resistor because voltage drop depends on current draw. If you choose a resistance value to drop 5V at 2.1A then if at any time the TV draws less than 2.1A the output voltage will rise above 19V.

So you need a circuit that *regulates* the output voltage so it remains stable when load current varies. The two main classes of regulator are *linear* and *switching*.

A linear regulator acts like a variable resistor which is continuously adjusted to keep the output voltage constant. It suffers the same power dissipation problems as a resistor, but has the advantage of a relatively simple circuit.

Switching regulators pulse current through an inductor to 'transform' the voltage down. They can be over 90% efficient because the inductor stores and releases the pulse energy rather than wasting it as heat. The disadvantage is a more complex circuit with critical component specifications and circuit layout.

Using a linear regulator to drop 24V down to 19V at 2.1A would waste (24-19)*2.1 = 10.5W. You would need a fairly large heat sink to remove this heat. However the circuit efficiency would be 79% which is not bad. A 90% efficient switching regulator would only dissipate 4.4W.

The [LM2596](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) is a switching regulator IC that only needs a few components to complete the circuit. Here's an example from the datasheet:-

[image]

However this apparent simplicity is a bit deceptive because for best performance the inductor characteristics have to be carefully matched to the input and output voltages and current.

You could try building a switching regulator using the LM2596 with the datasheet to guide you, or just buy a ready-made module that uses a similar chip. These are cheap and readily available from eBay and electronic hobbyist suppliers (eg. [IC Station](http://www.icstation.com/buck-converter-step-down-module-lm2596-123v-ripple-power-supply-p-1383.html)).

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8dRtV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's a rather hacky alternative to Bruce Abbott's answer.  A silicon rectifier diode drops about 0.6V when forward biased,  If you wire 8 of them in series, that's pretty close to the 5V drop required.  Make sure the diodes are traditional silicon rectifier diodes, and rated 3A or more.

Edit: This is "efficient" in the sense of cheap and easy.  It does not have a good power efficiency, as the diodes will all get warm.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to get a 19 V supply and stop trying to make the round peg fit the square hole.

If you really want to use the 24 V supply, then first see if you can adjust it down to 19 V.  That's rather a lot for a adjustable 24 V supply, but it's worth a try.

Otherwise, use a buck converter.  There are many chips out there, and it's not too hard to roll your own either.  The TV will have its own internal regulators, so a little ripple on the 19 V supply shouldn't matter.  A simple pulse on demand system should work plenty well enough.

A linear regulator is also not a good idea.  One of those would burn up (24 V - 19 V)(2.1 A) = 10.5 W in heat.  Getting rid of that heat would be more complicated, costly, and larger than a buck switcher.

Comment: I should have provided more info, the 24V is not adjustable, (yacht house bank).